# Is it possible to have a script running behind a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

#### The problem

I'm trying to write an extension that operates on a tab manipulating the DOM and redirecting to pages if necessary.

The exact logic of the program should be able to follow these steps:

- get some data from the background script
- redirect to page X
- if there's a form in the DOM then fill it and then move to page X again
- if on page X there's something else then redirect to page Y otherwise select this option
- etc.

These steps should only occur on specific tabs opened by the background script.

#### What I've read about

I've read that there are two kind of scripts that can be run by a Chrome extension:

- background script
- content script

As far as I know the former cannot access DOM inside tabs directly, but they can redirect a tab to a specific page via `chrome.tabs.update(..., { url: ... })`; while the latter can access the DOM but cannot redirect directly to a URL.

#### Messages are messy

With messages the whole script would be extremely messy, for example for the first couple of steps I would have to:

- background: spawns tab and injects script to check if there's the form
- content: if there's a form fill it and submit the form then send message to redirect back
- background: receive message and redirect to the requested page
- background: (maybe detect we are on said page) and inject content script
- content: if there's something else, if there's then send message to redirect back otherwise select option
- etc.

It becomes messy very quickly.

#### The question

What would be the best option for writing such a script?

Comment: [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can help you to do same;

Comment: yeah, and a content script can easily redirect with location.href = 'http://other.url/...'